# Add a item to eclipse package explorer's right-click menu

Tags: eclipse, right-click, package-explorer

I want to add a item to eclipse package explorer's right-click menu.

Any one has ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start at [Menu Contributions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions) wiki page. It has extensive list of examples.